# How to get Play Framework current running application instance in JUnit test cases

Tags: junit, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am working in Java Play Framework project. I want to write some JUnit test cases to test my application code.

Now for my JUnit cases, I need to initiate the play server Application to get all the configuration.

How do I get current play Application instance to initiate my Global ServerConfig in JUnits

Example type of code:

```
@Test
TestCode(){

Global.init(CurrentApplication_Instance);
//tes

}
```

Where **`CurrentApplication_Instance`** should be current running `play.Play.application()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend your Test-Class from `play.test.WithApplication` which starts an application at the beginning of the test and provides it as a property. So you could:

```
public class MyTest extends play.test.WithApplication {
    @Test
    TestCode(){
        Global.init(app);
    }
}
```